# What happens if a kalashtar becomes possessed?

Tags: dnd-5e, eberron, possession

Kalashtar have Quori spirits inside of them. How would the Quori spirit react to being possessed? *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* says that there can be adverse effects if a kalashtar ends up being an evil alignment, would this apply to being possessed by an evil PC?

Would being possessed by an evil PC have the same effects as being an evil character in regards to the Quori spirits' response and the adverse effects that come with an evil aligned kalashtar?

Comment: This question currently seems overly broad like idea generation that might be better addressed in a forum like reddit or enworld.  Are you specifically asking what are the adverse effects of an evil kalashtar and if those effects apply when the kalashtar is under the effects of possession by an evil caster?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Kalashtar have no special reactions to possession

*Eberron: Rising to the Last War* simply doesn’t mention any, and there are no “hidden rules,” as we like to say—so the rules say that kalashtar are subject to possession the same as anyone else, and nothing special happens. The book discusses quori possessing humanoids, and the Chosen and Inspired are already possessed by quori, but kalashtar have a different relationship between their shared souls.

As for “adverse effects if a kalashtar ends up being evil alignment,” this is something the kalashtar themselves believe in, not necessarily a mechanical effect.

Finally, I’d comment that this is consistent with the portrayals of kalashtar from the beginning, when they first appeared in D&D 3.5e:

- The original *Eberron Campaign Setting*, which was where kalashtar debuted (pg. 16–18), also included lengthy rules about possession (pg. 100–103). Neither the original description of kalashtar nor the considerable rules about possession in the same book make any mention of a special interaction between kalashtar and possession.
- *Secrets of Sarlona* is effectively an entire 3.5e **book** about the quori and kalashtar, and while it mentions possession a lot, it is **always** in the context of quori possessing creatures, such as the Chosen and Inspired, and kalashtar aren’t described in the same way (though they can take “Host feats,” *Secrets of Sarlona* is careful not to describe those as requiring that one be possessed—it actually talks about the *host* possessing the shared spirit).
- *Races of Eberron* included an entire chapter on kalashtar (pg. 55–70), plus numerous kalashtar-specific options outside that chapter; again, just about nothing about possession with respect to kalashtar.

The **only** reference I can find to the idea that kalashtar have any particular relationship with possession is on page 134 of *Races of Eberron*, where the kalashtar-only prestige class “atavist” gets an ability called “detect possession,” that when used, among other things, says

> you learn whether that creature is possessed by a quori spirit (true of both kalashtar and the Inspired),

<sup>(*Races of Eberron* pg. 134)</sup>

Considering the considerable and conspicuous lack of any mention of kalashtar’s shared spirit being related to possession anywhere else, I chalk this one exception up to a poor wording choice by the author of the atavist, and nothing more. In any event, it certainly hasn’t been repeated in D&D 5e.